# Working with cookies out of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, cookies

I want to make simple authentication like

```
# SessionController
require 'session.rb'
def create
  Session.new(params[:email], params[:password])
end

# lib/session.rb
class Session
  def initialize(email, password)
    client = Client.find_by_email_and_password(email, password)
    cookies[:user_id] = client.id if client
  end
end
```

only problem here is that I can't use cookies or sessions out of controller. I can replace cookies setting into controller, but it isn't what I want :)

Question is how to use cookies out of controller and what are best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't explicitly add '.rb' to a require statement. You'd just use `require 'session'` normally. Second, Rails will load it for you when you reference `Session`, so you don't need to require it explicitly. Also, `client ? cookies[:user_id] = client.id` is invalid Ruby code. You probably want `cookies[:user_id] = client.id if client`.

An obvious solution would be to simply pass the `cookies` object to the `Session` you're creating, but my recommendation would be to simply put the code in the controller. Why do you have a `Session` object in the first place? I'd recommend not overcomplicating things by creating an unnecessary class.

**Update:**

To illustrate my last comment, here's some sample code:

```
class Session
  attr_reader :controller

  def initialize(controller)
    @controller = controller
  end

  def client
    if controller.cookies[:user_id]
      return Client.find_by_id(controller.cookies[:user_id])
    elsif (email = controller.params[:email]) && (password = controller.params[:password])
      client = Client.find_by_email_and_password(email, password)
      controller.cookies[:user_id] = client.id if client
      return client
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `client ? cookies[:user_id] = client.id` in original was `cookies[:user_id] = client.id if client`. I want to create authentication in authlogic way `UserSession.create(:login => "bjohnson", :password => "my password", :remember_me => true)`. As I understand, authlogic extends model and sets up session inside of itself

Comment: Unless you're doing it to learn how it's done, don't do it yourself. Use Devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.

Comment: I need really simple authentication (10 lines of code). And I am digging into authlogic sources, but it still not clear to me, how it sets sessions up from model. Devise is great, but it is too fat for my purposes. I can set cookies inside of my controller, but I really want to extract it into external class :)

Comment: Authentication in 10 lines of code is pretty much guaranteed to be broken. You will probably be vulnerable to timing attacks. You won't have forgotten password functionality. You will be vulnerable to brute-force password attacks. You won't have much in the way of input validation. You won't have email verification. You won't have login tracking/counting. And unless you're the only user of this system (in which case, why are you building authentication?) you will want these things. Use Devise.

Comment: It is not public project. It is simply secured with session token and password encryption. I don't need any email notifications, openid support, facebook connection and other cool stuff :) Authentification is working fine and secure enough. Only problem is to **learn** how to extract cookies managment outside of controller into Session class

Comment: I'll say it one more time: don't do it until you need to. Disclaimer out of the way, what I'd probably do is have a `Session` which takes a controller instance in its initializer. Then it should have a method (`user` or something) that'll figure out what user is associated with the request and return it, reading/writing cookies as needed.

Comment: Brian, great update! Thans. Only question. How can I in Rails send controller itself from its action? `def create; Session.new(self.class); end

Comment: It's be just `def create; Session.new(self); end`. You may, of course, want to do something with that session once you have it, like so: `def create; @client = Session.new(self).client; end`.